# dose someone know asp.net core app 503 error with ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Tags: iis

when i change identity to localservice restart,it`s work,but why?applicationPoolIdentity created by default,it should has power with site folder,and when site run,i change identity to ApplicationPoolIdentity again,still work,dose some one know doc with it?

Answer (score 0):

"it should has power with site folder". No. That's not correct.

Many permissions are granted by server administrators after deploying a web app and they don't come automatically.

For example, `IIS_IUSRS` has read and execute permissions in `\inetpub\wwwroot` only because that's the folder for the sample Default Web Site.

If you create a new site then you are responsible to grant `IIS_USRS` the permissions there. From security perspective, that's the right way to go, and this behavior was there since at least IIS 6 (two decades ago).

## Reference

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/default-permissions-user-rightshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/default-permissions-user-rights#inetpubwwwroot